# .htaccess infinite loop, appends / to URL until redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/portal>
        Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$:\.)
        RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dashboard.php?url=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

The last directory definition is resulting in an infinite loop, `/` is appended to the URL around 10 times before Chrome fires a redirect loop error.

I'm not sure why this is happening as I used the same set up on another server and it worked fine. Is there anything wrong with this? All I'm trying to do is append a single `/` after the requested URL if one is not already present.

Any ideas why this is looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$:\.)
```

To this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, would you mind explaining what this changed to make it work?

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense, but you have also changed the order of the slashes and other characters, would this make any difference or is it just the pipe typo?